# Graph rotation: explanation of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Can someone please explain to me how in the attached image at the bottom right the author goes from $-y' = (-x')^2 -(-x')$ to $y = -x^2 - x$? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: $f(x)\to-f(-x)$ rotates f by $\pi$

Comment: Just remind that the quotes change the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$-y' = (-x')^2 -(-x')$

$-x'=x\quad\to\quad -y' = (x)^2 -(x)$

$-y'=y\quad\to\quad y = (x)^2 -(x)$

$y=x^2-x$

Answer (score 0):

$$-y'=(-x')^2-(-x')$$
$$-y'=(x')^2+x'$$
$$y'=-(x')^2-x'$$
At this point we only drop the $'$s to indicate that we will be graphing on the same axes.
$$y=-x^2-x$$

Answer (score 0):

Rotation by $\pi$ radians is actually a central symmetry, hence *if the center of rotation is the coordinate system's origin* then each coordinate is transformed to its opposite:
$x$ to $-x$ and $y$ to $-y$